# Console Application Execution

Tags: visual-studio-2012, console-application

I created a console application using Visual Studio 2012. It(EXE from Release folder) runs on the computer in which Visual Studio 2012 is installed, but it doesn't run on another computer which doesn't have Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Do you get any error message on other computers? Do you use any specific references from Visual Studio, that are not installed on the other machine?

Comment: I use references and the copy to directory option is set to true for all references. The application doesn't shows any error message, but a window appears with the text 'the program stopped working'.

Comment: do you have `.net framework` installed on another machine?

Comment: Yeah. I installed the required .NET framework 4.5.2 on another machine.

Comment: Did you ran your application on a machine where Visual Studio is installed and it worked their or why do you think it is related to Visual Studio? If you have references to Visual Studio libraries, why you want to run this on a machine without Visual Studio? It could also be, that you miss a dependent reference of the reference.

Comment: As you said it might be a dependent reference, which is not available for the application to run on another computer. Let me find out the dependent reference. First I should Console.Write the exception message in the catch block, which is empty right now. Hope we can find out that dependent reference by looking at that exception message.

Comment: Both VS2012 installed system and the other system which doesn't contain VS2012 has SQL Server 2008 r2 installed. And now I found the exception. It's the SQL server exception "Login failed for user". I think Visual Studio installed machine has some dependencies to provide privileges to the SQL server 2008 r2's windows login. But in the machine in which the visual studio is not installed, the console application can't login to SQL server 2008 r2 express.

Comment: Can you try to log on the SQL Server instance using SSMS from the other computer? Do you use integrated security in your connection string?

Comment: I uninstalled the SQL Server 2008 R2 Express and when I tried to install the SQL Server 2008 R2 with advanced services, the installer stopped to install in the middle of the installation showing the error "invalid user".

Comment: Let me try to reinstall SQL Server 2008 R2 with advanced services and check whether I can log on to SSMS and comment. If I can log on to SSMS, then I think the SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition installation needs some additional configuration to log on. But before that let me check with the SSMS login.

Comment: I reinstalled the SQL Server 2008 R2 with advanced services by correcting the 'same Machine Name and User Account name problem'. I can login when I use the SSMS. But can't login from express edition using CMD.